# Minio 403 Forbidden HEAD request using saveas (FileSaver.js)

Tags: cors, traefik, minio, filesaver.js

I try download file using FileSaver.js (`saveAs(minio-prefetch-url,'file.pdf')`) but request HEAD is send and minio response with 403:

```
Status Code: 403 Forbidden
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

```
Server: MinIO
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Vary: Origin
X-Amz-Id-2: dd9025bab4ad464b049177c95eb6ebf374d3b3fd1af9251148b658df7ac2e3e8
X-Amz-Request-Id: 1790AD52C0D34F55
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Minio-Error-Code: SignatureDoesNotMatch
X-Minio-Error-Desc: "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method."
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

after failiure link is opened in new tab and the content (pdf) is shown. So Signature in url is valid.

I am using latest minio image: `quay.io/minio/minio:RELEASE.2023-10-16T04-13-43Z`
and traefik: `traefik:v2.10`

My app (GUI) is deployed on `app.example.com` and minio is deployed on `minio.example.com`. I also configure API cors via minio console:

[image]

Does anyone have similar problems? How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Did you use a CDN like Cloudflare for your Minio domain? If so, try disabling the cache for the Minio domain in the CDN.

Comment: I think I've found where the problem is. Minio returns the correct response: SignatureDoesNotMatch because the calculation of the signature also takes into account the method. Therefore, the signature is only correct for the GET method. The solution was to take over the file in Angular using the http client and then use filesaver.js for writing the blob, i.e., for the transfer.

Comment: this one worked for me, disabled cache for minio from CF now its working